# how to get selected value of radio in reactive form

Tags: angular, radio-button, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I am trying to get the selectedValue of the radio button and pass it as true with the radio text. selectedValue to be sent as true if Choice 1 is selected else false. And selectedValue to be sent as true if Choice 2 is selected, else false. I could not set it to true. Was wondering if anyone has done this before?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xfrezb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, always include the relevant code in your question as code blocks, since links tend to die over time...

But as for your question, since you are dealing with several questions and dynamic `value`, I would pass the current formArray `components` and the current `answer`. You would need to first then set all form controls `selectedValue` as `false`, since otherwise toggling the radio buttons each would eventually become `true` of clicking every of them. So after first setting all as `false` then just set the chosen radio button as `true`. So do something like this:

```html
<div *ngIf="question.controls.type.value === 'radio'">
  <p>{{ question.controls.label.value }}</p>
  <div formArrayName="component">
    <div *ngFor="let answer of question.controls.component.controls; 
                 let j = index" [formGroupName]="j">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-stacked" 
           (click)="updateSelection(question.controls.component.controls, answer)">
          <span>{{ answer.value.value }}</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then your `updateSelection` method:

```ts
updateSelection(formArr, answer) {
  formArr.forEach(x => {
    x.controls.selectedValue.setValue(false);
  });
  answer.controls.selectedValue.setValue(true);
}
```

Your forked **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lo6hfd?file=app/app.component.ts)**

PS, what you could of course consider doing, is not to have **all** choices in your form object, but just add the value of the radio button you have chosen.

Comment: Thank you Alex! It's awesome, exactly what I was looking for. Did not know I have to use setValue. I need to send all the choices in the form object..so the backend Java Developers know the exact choice and selected value to update the database..Thanks again!

Comment: You are very welcome! Yes, always setting values to form controls, we need to use `setValue`. Or if you have for example a form group and want to just set some values belonging to that form group you can use `patchValue`: `this.myForm.patchValue({ ... })` if you were to use `setValue` in the same scenario, you need to provide all values for the form controls in that formgroup. But yes, glad to hear this solution was viable for you! :) Have a nice end of the weekend :)

Comment: Hi @Alex - Thank you so much for your help in radio selected value..I couldn't get the same working for drop down. Could you please help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48517602/how-to-get-selected-value-of-dropdown-in-reactive-form

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the presentation view and the value of the form. I think that it's better separate the concepts. We can use formObj to create the presentation, and callbackForm for the value. See the comments in the code

//app.main.html

```
<form [formGroup]="callbackForm" (submit)=submit(callbackForm)>
  <div>
    <div formArrayName="componentDetails">
        <div *ngFor="let question of callbackForm.controls.componentDetails.controls; let i = index;" [formGroupName]="i">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 panel-group panel-group--compressed">
                    <div class="panel panel--default">
                        <fieldset>
<!--see that we create the "view of the form using formObj.componentDetails--!>
                            <div class="row" *ngIf="formObj.componentDetails[i].type === 'radio'">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <p>{{ formObj.componentDetails[i].label }}</p>
                                    <p>{{ formObj.componentDetails[i].cpv }}</p>
<!-- we iterate throught "formObj.componentDetails[i].component -->
<!-- again, we are using formObj to the "view" -->
                                    <div *ngFor="let answer of formObj.componentDetails[i].component; let j = index">
                                       <label class="radio radio--alt radio--stacked">
                                            <span class="radio__input"></span>
                                             <span class="radio__label">{{ answer.value }}</span>
                                        </label>
<!--We have a input with name=formObj.componentDetails[i].cpv -->
<!--it's necesary enclose between {{ }} the name -->
                                        <input type="radio" formControlName="{{formObj.componentDetails[i].cpv}}" [value]="answer.selectedValue">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button type="submit">send</submit>
</form>
<pre>{{callbackForm.value | json}}</pre>
```

//app-main.component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-app-main',
  templateUrl: './app-main.component.html'

})
export class AppMainComponent {

  constructor(private _formBuild: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadObservableForm();
  }

  public callbackForm: FormGroup;

  formObj = {
    "componentDetails": [{
      "component": [{
        "value": "Choice 1",
        "selectedValue": true
      }, {
        "value": "Choice 2",
        "selectedValue": false
      }],
      "cpv": "name1",  //<--we use this to create the name of the fileld
      "label": "Description of Problem",
      "type": "radio",
      "mandatory": true
    }]
  };

  loadObservableForm() {
    this.callbackForm = this._formBuild.group({
      componentDetails: this._formBuild.array([])
    });
    this.addComponentDetails();
  }

  addComponentDetails() {
    const control = <FormArray>this.callbackForm.controls.componentDetails;
    this.formObj.componentDetails.forEach(x => {
      control.push(this.addControl(x));
    });
  }

  addControl(x) {
    //we create a group control with a control with a name "x.cpv"
    const group = this._formBuild.group({});
    group.addControl(x.cpv,new FormControl());
    return group;
  }
```

We have a callbackForm in the way "componentDetails": [{"name1": false},{"name2":value2}...]. So, in the submit we can do some like

```
submit(form)
{
   if (form.valid)
   {
       let response:any={}
       for (let control of form.value.componentDetails)
          response={...response,...control}

       console.log(response);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eliseo..It is an interesting concept to separate formObj and callbackForm. I will also try this.