# how to get selected value of dropdown in reactive form

Tags: angular-reactive-forms, angular4-forms, formarray, formgroups

I am trying to get the selected value of the dropdown on change event to be sent on reactive form submission. I have a very similar scenario working for radio based on the answer from [how to get selected value of radio in reactive form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471846/how-to-get-selected-value-of-radio-in-reactive-form?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Here's the code for dropdown

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="question.controls.type.value === 'dropdown'">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group__text select">
      <label for="type">{{ question.controls.label.value }}</label>
      <br><br>
      <select name="value" formArrayName="component" (change)="updateSelection(question.controls.component.controls, $event.target)">
        <option
          *ngFor="let answer of question.controls.component.controls; let j = index" [formGroupName]="j"
          [ngValue]="answer?.value?.value">
            {{answer?.value?.value}}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I am not able to pass the answer as formcontrol to updateSelection on change of a selected option from the dropdown. Any help is greatly appreciated.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-acdcac

Comment: what you want ? you want to get which choice is selected ?

Comment: yes Arun! I want the selectedValue to be true for a choice that is selected from the dropdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very similarily like previous question, we iterate the form controls in your array, initially set all as `false`, and then turn the chosen choice as `true`. So template let's pass `$event.target.value`:

```html
<select name="value" formArrayName="component" 
   (change)="updateSelection(question.controls.component.controls, $event.target.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let answer of question.controls.component.controls; let j = index" [formGroupName]="j"
       [ngValue]="answer?.value?.value">
       {{answer?.value?.value}}
  </option>
</select>
```

And in the component we as mentioned iterate the form controls and set all as `false`. The value for `$event.target.value` will be the string value, for example `Choice 1`. We then search for the form control that has that value and then set the boolean for that particular formgroup:

```ts
updateSelection(formArr, answer) {
  formArr.forEach(x => {
    x.controls.selectedValue.setValue(false)
  })
  let ctrl = formArr.find(x => x.value.value === answer)
  ctrl.controls.selectedValue.setValue(true)
}
```

Your forked **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v2yhbv?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: works as a charm! Thank you @Alex. It works by passing the value as I was wondering if I had to pass the form control instead similar to the radio